# Google Places API for Android (AutoComplete) returns Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null} on some devices

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have already checked several posts to find solution for this issue and I have ensured that my app follows all guidelines like :

1. I have enabled the "Google Places API for Android" in the console
2. I have used right API key in my manifest for com.google.android.geo.API_KEY
3. I have included Places.GEO_DATA_API while building the GoogleApiClient

However, I have NOT included the following permission in my manifest since as per documentation, this is not required any more if we target version 8.3 or higher :

It works fine in most of the devices; however, some of our customers have reported this problem on few devices like Moto G, Samsung and Xiomi running Google Play Services 9.0.82 and 9.0.83 versions

Any hints to solve this error would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Shobhana